# Is Stripe subscription metadata consistent

Tags: stripe-payments

Lets assume I set up a subscription in Stripe, and in my first payment of that subscription I include some arbitrary metadata. Will all payments that follow in the subscription have the same metadata as the original payment, or will their metadata default to empty?

Comment: What kind of arbitrary metadata you are trying to include? All the required and optional fields are explained in detail in Stripe documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata on the invoices will not be repeated